# change the behaviour of browse button

Tags: html, file, input, google-drive-api

Assume that you have a html page with browse button if you click the browse button it ll open folder in your computer or laptop right from their you can select the file what you want to upload but what my question is instead of opening a folder in our computer/laptop it ll open cloud server like one drive, google drive, etc., from their i want to select the files and upload it to my computer/laptop how to do that, actually i did some research about this but i didn't get any worthy website to learn about this.

Comment: what does that have to do with codeigniter....

Comment: i think you need to download particular file in you computer. If that is the case you have to user client rest api of google for Google drive from there you can build custom app to do so....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the behaviour of browse button instead you can use google picker api for selecting the file from google drive similarly you can use dropbox chooser for selecting the file from dropbox 
Try https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser#js - Dropbox
    https://github.com/tanmaykm/jquery-gdrive - google drive